# What's the difference between Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec and Text.Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
Text
    Text.Parsec
        Text.Parsec.ByteString
            Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy
        Text.Parsec.Char
        Text.Parsec.Combinator
        Text.Parsec.Error
        Text.Parsec.Expr
        Text.Parsec.Language
        Text.Parsec.Perm
        Text.Parsec.Pos
        Text.Parsec.Prim
        Text.Parsec.String
        Text.Parsec.Token
    ParserCombinators
        Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Combinator
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Error
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Perm
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Pos
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim
            Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token
```

Are they the same?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

At the moment there are two widely used major versions of Parsec: Parsec 2 and
Parsec 3.

My advice is simply to use the latest release of Parsec 3. But if you want to
make a conscientious choice, read on.

### New in Parsec 3

#### Monad Transformer

Parsec 3 introduces a monad transformer, `ParsecT`, which can be used to combine
parsing with other monadic effects.

#### Streams

Although Parsec 2 lets you to choose the token type (which is useful when you
want to separate lexical analysis from the parsing), the tokens are always
arranged into lists. List may be not the most efficient data structure in which to store
large texts.

Parsec 3 can work with arbitrary *streams* -- data structures with a list-like
interface. You can define your own streams, but Parsec 3 also includes a popular
and efficient Stream implementation based on ByteString (for `Char`-based
parsing), exposed through the modules `Text.Parsec.ByteString` and
`Text.Parsec.ByteString.Lazy`.

### Reasons to prefer Parsec 2

#### Fewer extensions required

Advanced features provided by Parsec 3 do not come for free; to implement them
several language extensions are required.

Neither of the two versions is Haskell-2010 (i.e. both use extensions), but
Parsec 2 uses fewer extensions than Parsec 3, so chances that any given compiler
can compile Parsec 2 are higher than those for Parsec 3.

By this time both versions work with GHC, while Parsec 2 is also [reported](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2011-January/022532.html) to
build with JHC and is included as one of the JHC's standard libraries.

#### Performance

Originally (i.e. as of 3.0 version) Parsec 3 was considerably slower than
Parsec 2. However, [work on improving Parsec 3 performance](http://panicsonic.blogspot.com/2009/12/adventures-in-parsec.html) has been  done,
and as of version 3.1 Parsec 3 is only slightly slower than Parsec 2
(benchmarks: [1](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-December/070196.html), [2](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg79296.html)).

### Compatibility layer

It has been possible to "reimplement" all of the Parsec 2 API in Parsec 3. This
compatibility layer is provided by the Parsec 3 package under the module hierarchy
`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec` (the same hierarchy which is used by Parsec 2),
while the new Parsec 3 API is available under the `Text.Parsec` hierarchy.

This means that you can use Parsec 3 as a drop-in replacement for Parsec 2.

Comment: The link about transformers seems to fail now.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I've removed it.

Comment: Is Text.Parsec == Parsec 3 and  Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec  == Parsec 2?

Answer (score 18):

I believe the latter is a backwards-compatible layer for Parsec 2, implemented in terms of the newer API.