# Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec or Text.Parsec. What is the difference?

Tags: haskell, parsec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the different between Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec and Text.Parsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029371/whats-the-different-between-text-parsercombinators-parsec-and-text-parsec)

Is there any difference between the two? Which one should I use?

Comment: Take a look at that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029371/whats-the-different-between-text-parsercombinators-parsec-and-text-parsec

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't seen that one. I guess this should be closed then.