# Parsec: Which module to import?

Tags: haskell, parsec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the different between Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec and Text.Parsec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029371/whats-the-different-between-text-parsercombinators-parsec-and-text-parsec)

Every time I'm importing Parsec modules, there are two choices: `Text.Parsec` and `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec`. I couldn't find any information on what these two do differently (the `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec` main Haddock page only mentions that it's some kind of compatibility module, while there is no introductory sentence in `Text.Parsec` at all).

So this left me wondering: What's the difference between the two packages, which one should I prefer under different circumstances?